# Does $\lim \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=1$ tell us anything about $\lim f(x)-g(x)$ or vice versa?

Tags: real-analysis, limits

This is not homework or anything, but I just had a random idea and I'm not really sure where to go with it.

The equations:
$$ \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=1$$
$$ \lim_{x \to \infty} f(x)-g(x) = 0$$

Are both ways of roughly saying that as $x$ gets really large, $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ get really close to each other. My question is, do either of these statements imply the other?

By taking logs of the first equation, we can see that it implies 
$$\lim_{x \to \infty} \log(f(x))-\log(g(x))=0$$,
 and by exponentiating the second equation, we get that $$\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{e^{f(x)}}{e^{g(x)}}=1$$

Other than that, I haven't really noticed anything. Anybody have any insight?

Comment: How about working some examples? What about $f(x) = x^2 + x$ and $g(x) = x^2$? Or $f(x) = 1/x^2$ and $g(x) = 1/x$?

Comment: It is easy to prove that if $\lim_{x\to\infty}g(x)$ exists and is not zero, then $\lim_{x\to\infty}(f(x)-g(x))=0$ implies that $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=1$ (consider $\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}-1$). This is not true in general.

Comment: Since it was just a random idea here is a random way to think about this idea you had.  Let $f(x)$ be your girlfriend's (or boyfriend's) age at time $x$ and let $g(x)$ be your age at time $x$.  The first limit says the ratio of the ages is tending to $1$ which, on this planet at least, is true.  But the second difference isn't going to change as time goes on.

Comment: @B.S.Thomson wow, what a great way to think about it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first does not imply the second.   Consider $f(x)=x^2+x$,  $g(x)=x^2$.   Then the limit of the quotient is 1, but the limit of the difference diverges to infinity.

The second will definitely imply the first if the limits are finite.  I'm pretty sure it should be in general, but can't provide a proof of it right now.   But the difference going to 0 says they are much closer than the quotient going to 1

Comment: The second does not imply the first, I don't think.

Comment: $\frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = \frac{f(x) - g(x)}{g(x)} + 1$, so it's true at least if $g$ stays away from $0$.

Comment: If, for example $f$ and $g$ both tend to infinity, then as $x$ gets large $g$ would have to stay away from zero, so the statement must hold, right?

Answer (score 2):

you can't say anything about $\lim_{x \to \infty}(f - g)$ with $\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac fg = 1.$

here are some counter examples:

(1) $f(x) = x, g(x) =x \pm \sqrt x$ here we have $\lim_{x \to \infty}f(x) - g(x) = \mp \infty$

(2) $f(x) = x, g(x) =x \pm 1$ here we have $\lim_{x \to \infty}f(x) - g(x) = \mp 1$